# android studio is not working using ionic capacitor

Tags: android-studio, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am using ionic framework capacitor for android development. When I run the following command on command prompt:
`ionic capacitor run android`
The android studio is opened. But It is showing the following error:

Migrate Project to Gradle?
This project does not use the Gradle build system. We recommend that you migrate to using the Gradle build system.
More Information about migrating to Gradle
Don't show this message again.

01:00   'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
01:00   * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
01:00   * daemon started successfully

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

[image]

Comment: open the Command Prompt as Administrator : `net stop winnat` then 
`net start winnat`

Comment: it is not work for me

Comment: You are not building the project.
1. ionic build
2.npx cap sync
3.  npx cap open android
OR run live 
3. ionic capacitor run android -l --external --adress